# Ruby > Inject method > Accumulating strings in an array

Tags: ruby, rubygems

All,

New to Ruby and playing around. Here's my array:

```
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "pear", "orange"]
```

I accumulated like this:

```
longest_sentence = fruits.inject("banana") do |memo, fruit|
  if memo == fruits[0]
    puts "I like " + fruit + "s and "
  else
    puts fruit + "s and "
  end
end
```

As expected, it gave me this:

```
I like bananas and 
apples and 
pears and 
oranges and 
=> nil
```

Here's are my two questions:

1. How would you condense this code into a single line (i.e.no code block)?
2. How would you display the results as a single string (i.e. "I like bananas and apples and pears and oranges and" without the awkward line returns)?

Thanks!

Comment: "I like apples and oranges and" is invalid english :)

Answer (score 2):

The argument you pass to `reduce` should be the initial value you want `memo` to have. In this case, it looks like you want it to be `"I like"`. Additionally, don't do `puts` inside the block. `reduce` (like `map` et al) is for "building" objects. Once you're done, then print the string you built:

```
sentence = fruits.inject("I like") do |memo, fruit|
  memo << " #{fruit}s and"
end

puts sentence
# => I like bananas and apples and pears and oranges and
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inject/reduce for this.

```
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "pear", "orange"]
puts "I like " + fruits.map{|f| f + 's'}.join(' and ') 
# >> I like bananas and apples and pears and oranges
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "I like #{fruits.join('s and ')}s" 
  #-> I like bananas and apples and pears and oranges
```

or

```
puts "I like %ss" % fruits.join("s and ")
```